# What's the difference between ARSession delegate methods?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am in the process of making a Swift app that currently places some simple shapes onto a reference image using an `ARImageAnchor` and an `ARReferenceImage`. Right now, all of the augmented content is being placed within the `session(_:didAdd:)` function, however I know there is also a `session(_:didUpdate:)` function. The `didAdd` version makes sense, since it just runs when an anchor is added. But the Apple documentation is a bit vague about the exact purpose of this second version:

```
func session(ARSession, didUpdate: [ARAnchor])

// Tells the delegate that the session has adjusted 
// the properties of one or more anchors.
```

Does this mean any time the anchors move within the scene this function will run? Or is "properties" referring to something other than just the position of the anchors? I am just a bit confused what this second function would be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Foreword

I agree with you that Apple's documentation is often unclear.

ARKit and/or RealityKit apps are built on a running ARSession object that is a key AR element based on a specific [configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration). Each configuration type in ARKit allows you to generate specific [ARAnchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502) (`ARPlaneAnchor`, `ARImageAnchor`, `ARFaceAnchor`, etc). In ARKit, we must use an explicit (manual) configuration, while in RealityKit, a configuration is automatic, due to the fact it's set according to the AnchorEntity type (`.plane`, `.image`, `.face`, etc).

ARKit anchors can be tracked by implementing the [session(...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate) or [renderer(...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate) delegate methods. ARKit anchors may be accessed through each ARFrame (60 frames per second).

```
arView.session.currentFrame?.anchors
```

RealityKit anchors are automatically (implicitly) tracked by the application. RealityKit anchors' collection can be accessed through the [Scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593960/whats-the-difference-between-aranchor-and-anchorentity/57630001#57630001) object.

```
arView.scene.anchors
```

The ARKit and RealityKit frameworks can work together or separately from each other. RealityKit's AnchorEntity is capable of using ARKit's ARAnchor transform to place a model into a scene:

```
self.anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: arAnchor)
```

## Use case

***ARSessionDelegate*** protocol has 4 optional `session(...)` methods that you can use with both frameworks. The first pair of `session(...)` methods are used quite often. `session(_:didAdd:)` instance method is used to `add`/`extract` specific anchors `to`/`from` an ARSession under certain conditions. However, `session(_:didUpdate:)` instance method allows you to update the content, based on a specific ARAnchor's data. It can be accomplished this way:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    
    guard let faceAnchor = anchors.first as? ARFaceAnchor
    else { return }
                    
    self.geometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
    self.facialExpression(anchor: faceAnchor)
}
```

[THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347327/realitykit-visualizing-grid-on-detected-planes/71351712#71351712) shows you how to use both methods together.

And read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241779/how-do-i-specify-a-child-node-location-relative-to-arimageanchor/71627765#71627765) to find out how to use `session(_:didUpdate:)` method alone.